# how to remove embeded objects from word using c# interop?

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-interop

I am trying to get pdf/word/excel embeded documents & remove it.
but, instead of embededOleObject it detects is as an MSOPicture type.

I am using document.InlineShapes & iterating it inlineshape and checking it's type.
It detects as MSOPicture insted of embdedOleObject or embededLinkedOleObject.

can anyone suggest how can I detect correct inlineshape type?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject